Would it be valid to say $y \propto 2x$ instead of $y \propto x$?
Would it be acceptable to write $y \propto 2x$ or would it be wrong to add the $2$? I just want to describe a relationship in more detail.

Voting to reopen. This is a perfectly clear question with a good answer below.

@gandalf61 I agree. I have tidied up the question.

If what you mean is $y=2x$, then write that. If what you mean is that $y$ is proportional to $x$, then it is also proportional to $2x$, $3x$, $17.9x$, $\pi x$, etc. so why would you pick $2x$?

I don't think it would be wrong, but perhaps unusual and it doesn't really describe the relationship in more detail. $y\propto x$ simply means $$y=cx$$ where $c$ doesn't depend on $x$. For all you know, $c$ could be a million or $10^{-20}$ but those factors aren't really relevant for the relationship between $y$ and $x$ – that simply is that $y$ increases linearly with $x$. So usually, all constant factors are absorbed into the proportionality symbol.

or could i say y∝x with a slope of 2?

You "could" of course say that. However, I don't see why you would say that. If you already know, that $y$ depends linearly on $x$ and that the slope is $2$, why then not simply write $y = 2x$? Perhaps if you add some context, one could better understand why you want to use the $\propto$ symbol and if it makes sense.

It sure sounds like something physicists would write. Actually, if $c$ has dimensions, for any dimensional quantities writing $x\propto cy$ would be the only way for the statement to make sense. But of course, mathematicians do not concern themselves with these things too much

$y \propto 2x$ doesn't convey any more information than $y \propto x$. Therefore, while not technically incorrect, the inclusion of the $2$ is unnecessary. It doesn't add anything more.
